# Add scoreboard to "game"

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a small version of "duck hunt" I want to add a scoreboard when every time you hit the duck its +1 and when you miss its -1 but the score cant go lower than 0 (so not -1 for example) when you have tried 20 times the game stops and you will see your score so the hit and miss clicked times will show on the screen. How do I add this to my code so far I have got this:

```js
var duck = document.getElementById('duck');
duck.style.position = 'relative';
var hit = 0;
var miss = 0
var count = 0;
var timing = setInterval(moveduck, 5000);
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
duck.addEventListener('click', moveduck);

function moveduck() {
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var vertical = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var horizontal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  duck.style.top = top + 'px';
  duck.style.left = left + 'px';
  duck.style.right = right + 'px';
  duck.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
  duck.style.vertical = vertical + 'px';
  duck.style.horizontal = horizontal + 'px';
};


button1.onclick = succesfullhit;

function succesfullhit() {
  hit++;
  button1.innerHTML = hit;
}

button2.onclick = failedhit;

function failedhit() {
  miss--;
  button2.innerHTML = miss;
}
```

```css
#duck { height:50px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Duck hunt</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Duckhunt.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/duck-xxl.png" name="duck" id="duck" />
    <button id="button1">Hit: </button>
    <p></p>
    <button id="button2">Miss: </button>
  </div>
  <script src="Duckhunt.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this :
i changed the hit and miss and i did only score.
i added event listener to the document, if you hit the duck score++ if not score--
and i display the score.
i added if statement, if score is === -1 game over.
if score === 20 win

Of course you need to do a bit work to make it perfect for your need, this is just for the beginning.

```js
var duck = document.getElementById('duck');
duck.style.position = 'relative';
var score = 0
var timing = setInterval(moveduck, 5000);
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");


function moveduck() {
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var vertical = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var horizontal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  duck.style.top = top + 'px';
  duck.style.left = left + 'px';
  duck.style.right = right + 'px';
  duck.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
  duck.style.vertical = vertical + 'px';
  duck.style.horizontal = horizontal + 'px';
  score++
};

document.addEventListener("click", function(e){
if(score === -1){
    score = 0
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Game over'
    console.log('game over')
  }
if(score === 20){
    document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = 'Win'
    console.log('Win')
  }
  if (e.target.id === 'duck'){
    moveduck()
     document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score
  }else {
  score--
  document.getElementById('score').innerHTML = score
  }
})
```

```css
#duck { height:50px; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Duck hunt</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Duckhunt.css">
</head>

<body>
<div id="scoreBoard">Score: <p id="score"></p></div>
  <div class="container">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/duck-xxl.png" name="duck" id="duck" />
  </div>
  <script src="Duckhunt.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oh wow this is almost exactly what I meant. but is there a way to add something like this: http://www.nutty.ca/resource/images/games/duckhunt/Duck%20Hunt%20-%20Game%202.jpg at the end? I need to make a different html for something like that or i there a way to add it in this?

Comment: @desit900 here you go https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/KKMJpaJ

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start

```js
var duck = document.getElementById('duck');
duck.style.position = 'relative';
var hit = 0;
var miss = 0
var count = 0;
var timing = setInterval(moveduck, 5000);
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (hit+miss >= 20) return
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.id ==="duck") succesfullhit()
  else failedhit();
  if (hit+miss === 20) clearInterval(timing)
  else moveduck();
});

function moveduck() {
  var top = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var left = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var right = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var bottom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var vertical = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  var horizontal = Math.floor(Math.random() * 750);
  duck.style.top = top + 'px';
  duck.style.left = left + 'px';
  duck.style.right = right + 'px';
  duck.style.bottom = bottom + 'px';
  duck.style.vertical = vertical + 'px';
  duck.style.horizontal = horizontal + 'px';
};

function succesfullhit() {
  hit++;
  button1.innerHTML = hit;
}

function failedhit() {
  miss++;
  button2.innerHTML = -1*miss;
}
```

```css
#duck { height:50px; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/orange/duck-xxl.png" name="duck" id="duck" /><br/>
    <button id="button1">Hit: </button>
    <p></p>
    <button id="button2">Miss: </button>
  </div>
```